# Dynamic linking error when using ppx_compare

Tags: frama-c

In my own Frama-C plugin, I would like to use [ppx_compare](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_compare) for generation of compare functions. After adding the following line to my plugin's Makefile:

```
PLUGIN_REQUIRES = ppx_compare
```

the plugin is successfully compiled and installed, but running frama-c fails with the following error message:

```
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'base': cannot load module
  Details: The module `Base' is already loaded (either by the main program or a previously-dynlinked library)
[kernel] User Error: cannot load plug-in 'ppx_compare.runtime-lib': cannot load module
  Details: interface mismatch on Base
[kernel] User Error: Deferred error message was emitted during execution. See above messages for more information.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

This seems to be a conflict of Frama-C's Base module and Jane Street's Base library. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is no, at least for a workaround that could fit nicely in a SO answer. It should be possible to pack the Frama-C kernel as well as the plugins, but that would require significant changes in the compilation process.